# How to I properly use the min function in Haskell code?

Tags: haskell

```
main = print $ smallestFactor 15

factors n = [x | x <- [2..n], n `mod` x == 0]
smallestFactor n = min[factors n]
```

I understand that it's a pretty trivial question but someone told me that I could use min get grab out the smallest value of a element list. Though, I'm not exactly sure how one is suppose to use it.

Comment: You are looking for `minimum`: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:minimum

Comment: `min a b` takes two arguments, only. For a list of values, use `minimum list` instead. (And don't use square brackets like `[factors n]` unless you want a list with exactly one element inside)

Comment: `min` works for *two* items, `minimum` for a `Foldable` of items.

Answer (score 3):

You mean [`minimum :: Ord a => [a] -> a`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=minimum). Plus, you're erroneously using square brackets when you should be using parentheses. Don't use square brackets when you're not explicity defining a list!

Here's the corrected part:

```
smallestFactor n = minimum (factors n)
```

The rest of your code is fine.